# Invalid R Variable name error

Tags: r, reserved-words

below is the structure of my dataframe and i keep getting an error when i run some R code against it;

Error: At least one of the class levels is not a valid R variable name; This will cause errors when class probabilities are generated because the variables names will be converted to  X0, X1 . Please use factor levels that can be used as valid R variable names  (see ?make.names for help).

The code where the error is thrown is here;

```
objModel <- train(df.schools[,predictorsNames], df.schools[,outcomeName], 
              method='gbm', 
              trControl=objControl,  
              metric = "ROC",
              preProc = c("center", "scale"))
```

Any idea which factor level is causing this error?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Variables can't start with a number, so you have a few problems here, like "2-5hours", "4thPass", and more.  Change those to something starting with a letter and I think you'll be ok!

Comment: Applied those changes and still get the same error.

Comment: Did you just change the ones mentioned or all off the similar ones like "15-30mins" & "30min-1hour"  ?